# unable to run "canvas" tag and javascript program in aptana studio

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Below shown is my HTMLcode :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
   <title></title>
   <head>
      <script scr ="myprog.js"> </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id="main">
         <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

And my javascript code is as below:

```
function doFirst(){
   var x=document.getElementById('canvas');
   canvas=x.getContext('2d');
   canvas.strokeRect(10,10,100,200);
}

window.addEventListener("load",doFirst,false);
```

as per my understanding I'm suppose to get a rectangle of 100*200 in the browser(I'm using firefox browser). But here in my case, after running the above code I'm just getting a blank web page and I'm not getting any errors in the Aptana studio console too. Can anyone help me find out what the problem is?

I tried running a simple javascript program too ,to check if the my aptana studio can run javascript,and the following was the result:

1) when I added a button and tried to call a function using the below code,i got the alert after I clicked the button on the webpage(that is the program worked fine) :
`<input type="button"  value="click me" onClick="alert('hello')/>;`

2)But when I tried to run this particular code given below,i didn't get anything on my webpage:

```
doFunction(){
   alert('hello');
}
window.addEventListener("load",doFirst,false);

document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = "doFunction()";
```

3)I made sure that I linked my javascript file with my html using the code:
           `<script src="my prog.js"></script>`
so the problem is not with the linking I guess.

Kindly please someone help me out...
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvas= x.getContext('2d');
canvas.rect(10,10,100,200);;
canvas.stroke();
```

And put the script before the `</body>` tag

or if you want the script to be on top find the jQuery function for

```
 $( document ).ready(function()
```

hope i helped

Comment: I don't know what the problem was,but when i tried running it again,it worked. Sorry for bothering....And thanks for the reply